# access 2010 run time error message 3464

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a combo box field called cboYearQtr to retrieve that info and return data on that selection on the form. I get a data mismatch run time error 3464. The Date_YYYYQX field is a text field and i am calling myYearQtr a string in code. i do not understand why this throws the error here. i think it should work. I have looked on this site and else where and it looks correct to me.

Code:

```
Private Sub cboYearQtr_AfterUpdate()

Dim myYearQtr As String

myYearQtr = "Select Distinct Date_YYYYQX from [tbl_YYYYQX_LU] where [Date_YYYYQX] = " & Me.cboYearQtr & ""
[Forms]![frm_tbl_Drug_Master_Date_LU].Form.RecordSource = myYearQtr
[Forms]![frm_tbl_Drug_Master_Date_LU].Form.Requery


End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When building text strings to run sql you need to place `'` around the variable.

```
myYearQtr = "Select Distinct Date_YYYYQX from [tbl_YYYYQX_LU] where [Date_YYYYQX] = '" & Me.cboYearQtr & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks it didnt error now. I swear i tried that and got an error. Now on to the next part. Figuring out why it didnt return any records in the form when there is data. :)

Comment: Insert `Debug.Print myYearQtr` on a new line after the `myYearQtr =` line.  Run the code.  Examine the `SELECT` statement text in the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there.)  You can copy the statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.  It should return no more than 1 row (which makes me wonder why it is useful as a form's `RecordSource`, but whatever ...).  However, if it actually returns no row when you expect one, show us the SQL statement and a brief sample from `[tbl_YYYYQX_LU]` which should return one row but does not.

Comment: @HansUp - i ran it and found something odd. It looks like the sql is selecting the right myYearQtr in the table but the Form has the Date_YYYYQX as another date. I will do some more research on why the 2 tables i put on this form are not correct. Thanks for your help.